# Copy xml, increment date and replace/remove text all in one xslt file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to do 3 things here.  I am trying to:

1) Remove/replace text.
2) Copy XML up to 26 times
3) Change dates in XML to increment by 14 days 26 times.

Here is what I'm starting with:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<BB:Report_Data xmlns:BB="urn:com.playdate.report/Bi-Weekly_Outbound">
   <BB:Report_Entry>
      <BB:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>1234567</BB:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>     <BB:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4573945975</BB:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>   <BB:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</BB:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
  <BB:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>07072012</BB:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <BB:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</BB:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>VA</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      </BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>      <BB:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</BB:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>   <BB:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>07072012</BB:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <BB:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</BB:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>WR</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      </BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
 <BB:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323</BB:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>      <BB:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>07072012</BB:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <BB:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</BB:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>SS</BB:leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
      </BB:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
   </BB:Report_Entry>
</BB:Report_Data>
```

This is how it needs to end up:

```
<BB:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.playdate.report/Bi-Weekly_Outbound">
   <leaveBalanceTotal>
      <projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>1234567</projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
      <projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4573945975</projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>07072012</projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>VA</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>07072012</projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>WR</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323</projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>07072012</projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>SS</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
   </leaveBalanceTotal>
   <leaveBalanceTotal>
      <projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>1234567</projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
      <projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4573945975</projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>07212012</projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>VA</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>07212012</projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>WR</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323</projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>07212012</projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>SS</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
   </leaveBalanceTotal>
   <leaveBalanceTotal>
      <projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>1234567</projectedBalanceTotal.employeeId>
      <projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4573945975</projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
         <projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08042012</projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>VA</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08042012</projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>WR</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
         <projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323</projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>08042012</projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
         <projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>SS</leaveBalanceTotal.leaveDescription>
   </leaveBalanceTotal>
</BB:Report_Data>
```

.....etc, etc.until we hit 26

I already have xslt that successfully handles my remove/replace requirements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:bb="urn:com.workday.report/CR-INT486-Kuali_Trojan_Time-Absence_Balances__University_Bi-Weekly_-Outbound" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="bb">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bb:Report_Data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bb:Report_Entry">
        <leaveBalanceTotal>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </leaveBalanceTotal>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to put that transformation on top of whatever code will copy the xml 26 times and increment each data by 14 day as show above.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is my understanding correct that you want to transform the source XML document into another one (doing the text replacement and the date increment by 14 days), and then replicate this result 26 times? Or do you mean something else? Are you interested in an XSLT 2.0 solution (which is considerably easier than an XSLT 1.0 one)?

Comment: In both your input and output documents, you do not have a namespace declaration for BB. You do so for wd but it appears unused. I suspect that this is an error. Please clarify or correct.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 has nice inbuilt support for date functions (See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime). However date operations in XSLT 1.0 are a real pain. You could roll your own date addition function, but it would be a lot of work (see http://soajagat.blogspot.com.au/2009/06/xpath-10-datetime-nightmares.html for an example).

Comment: Hi everyone.  Sorry for the late reply.  I posted late on Friday and was out of town on personal business all weekend.  I corrected the namespace error...it was indeed a typo.

I am more than willing to try the 2.0 route especially if it is easier.  

@DimitreNovatchev, I am indeed trying to do what you've stated.  To be clear, I am trying to transform the source xml as you stated 26 times.  In each copy, the first dates will increment by another 14 days spanning 1 year after it's all done.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, it looks like the link you provided has helpful code in. Unfortunately I am at a loss on how to compile it.  I am finally taking a an xslt class but it doesn't start for 3 weeks.  Any help compiling this code would be great!!

Comment: So what is your XSLT engine? I suggest that you post another question on how to invoke an XSLT engine. Specify what engines you are constrained to use, and what o/s you are on.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin  It is a built into an enterprise SaaS program.  I think I have an idea that might be easier to handle using XSLT if you think this is too complicated.  

Let me know if you think this will work easier....I am thinking about delivering all 26 dates in the xml then using XLST to break them out into individual records the all other data fields being the same and the the only difference being the unique dates (projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate)

Comment: Yes, that would work. From what I understand SaaS produces your input XML document, it is not your XSLT engine. So what engine do you use for the transform?

Comment: Then engine is built into the SaaS program.  I config a program that calls a report and generates the xml.  I can then attach xls to the program that will transform the xml to the output format I need. I do not have direct access to the xslt engine to run a style sheet on its own. 

I am wondering if it might be easier for me to start a new question using the xml that has all 26 dates and work on parsing them out into 26 separate records instead of trying to increment the date using xlst.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is in reference to the comment thread. If you don't know what engine you are using, then run this style-sheet and tell us the results.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0" > 
      <xsl:output method = "text" /> 

      <xsl:template match = "/" > 
           <xsl:text >
  Version :  </xsl:text> 
           <xsl:value-of select = "system-property('xsl:version')" /> 
           <xsl:text >
    Vendor :  </xsl:text> 
           <xsl:value-of select = "system-property('xsl:vendor')" /> 
           <xsl:text >
    URL :  </xsl:text> 
           <xsl:value-of select = "system-property('xsl:vendor-url')" /> 
      </xsl:template> 
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am closing this out as I modified the report that's generating the xml in hopes of simplifying my task.  I opened a new question here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638723/complex-xml-to-xml-transformation-using-xslt

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this out as I modified the report that's generating the xml in hopes of simplifying my task.  I opened a new question here:   [Complex XML to XML Transformation using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638723/complex-xml-to-xml-transformation-using-xslt)