# Complex XML to XML Transformation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

this might not be complex to you all but it's extremely difficult for me.  This is my second attempt.  I have changed my data around to include more information that will take less to transform.

Basically I am trying to take data consisting of three vacation plans (VA, SS and WR) and project out the amount of time each plans will accrue each pay period, by worker, for an entire year.  I've only included three pay periods in my data to keep it short(er).  I need a separate record for each worker / effective date combination.  So if a worker has three vacations plans, and are paid bi-weekly (26 times / year), then that worker could have 78 records.

Here is the XML I am starting with (remember, I am only using the first 3 pay period dates in my example and not all 26):

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<bb:Report_Data xmlns:bb="urn:com.workday.report/Projected_Balances_Outbound">
   <bb:Report_Entry>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1238974569</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>

      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>

      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>

      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>123454</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </bb:Report_Entry>
   <bb:Report_Entry>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4545645878</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.692</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>

      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>

      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
         <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate2>
         <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate3>

      </bb:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>445241</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </bb:Report_Entry>
</bb:Report_Data>
```

This is what I need to the output to look like after the transformation:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<bb:Report_Data xmlns:bb="urn:com.workday.report/Projected_Balances_Outbound">
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1238974569</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>123454</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1238974569/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>123454</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1238974569/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.323</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>123454</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1238974569/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>123454</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1238974569/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>123454</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1238974569/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>123454</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1238974569/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>123454</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1238974569/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>123454</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>1238974569/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>123454</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>


   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4545645878/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.692</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>445241</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4545645878/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.692</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>445241</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4545645878/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>SS</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>3.692</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>445241</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4545645878/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>445241</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4545645878/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>445241</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4545645878/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>WR</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>445241</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4545645878/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07112012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>445241</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4545645878/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>07252012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>445241</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>4545645878/bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>VA</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId>
      <bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>0</bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>08082012</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate1>
      <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>445241</bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid>
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
</bb:Report_Data>
```

A few more things to take notice of... In addition to the format changes, I am removing the element tags "All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker" altogether and I am replacing "bb:Report_Entry" with "projectedBalanceTotal".

I have virtually no starting point except that I have XSL code written that successfully removes "All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker" and replaces "bb:Report_Entry" with "projectedBalanceTotal".  That can be found here:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR-INT486-Kuali_Trojan_Time-Absence_Balances__Hospital_Bi-Weekly_-Outbound" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="wd">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:All_Eligible_Time_Off_Plans_for_Worker">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
        <projectedleaveBalanceTotal>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </projectedleaveBalanceTotal>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be great!  Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Sorry, can't see the relationship between your input and output. None of the dates in your output seem to be present in the input; So where do they come from? And I don't understand your description of the transformation ("project out the amount of time each plans will accrue each pay period, by worker, for an entire year") You also need to say whether you need an XSLT 1.0 solution or whether 2.0 can be used. Suggestion: create a simpler toy problem that includes the essence of the real problem, so we have a chance of understanding it.

Comment: @MichaelKay ... my goodness I am very sorry.  I copied the wrong input file from notepad.  Thanks for the catch!!!  I edited my questions and changed the input file data.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:bb="urn:com.workday.report/Projected_Balances_Outbound">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <bb:Report_Data>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/*/*[starts-with(local-name(),'projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate')]"/>
 </bb:Report_Data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
<!-- Add predicate [starts-with(local-name(),'projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate')]
     to the match pattern if you feel like it. -->
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
     <xsl:copy-of select="
       ../../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId  |
       ../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId      |
       ../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId     |
       ../bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period |
       .                                           |
       ../../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid"   />
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Caveat

This outputs <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate\d> nodes, where "\d" means some integer. In your sample input, you have effectiveDate1, effectiveDate2 etc. However in your expected output have only effectiveDate1 . I didn't bother to rename all the effectiveDate\d nodes to effectiveDate1 because of the high probablity that this was just a clerical error on your part. So if you require all effectiveDate\d nodes to be called precisely effectiveDate1, then adjust accordingly.

### Learning note

If you want to self-solve similar problems in future, try this technique:

1. Remove all namespaces, unless namespaces are an intrinsic part of the problem to be solved.
2. Replace all long node names with short memorable ones like (banana, apple, pear).
3. Simplify and eliminate nodes down to the true nub of the problem. If you have two node types banana and apple treated to the same rules, just work with banana in your sample data.
4. Generate a number of use cases proportional to the complexity of your rules of transformation, and try to get the use cases to cover edge conditions, and be broadly ranged.
5. Treat XSLT with the same respect that you would any other programming language. If you had to write a program in Java, but you started with zero knowledge in that language, you would buy a book or attend a training course, right? Just like any other language, you can't learn it just by looking at examples on SO.

---

### Update

The OP has asked for a modification to the style-sheet so that the effectiveDate element is the output is without a number embedded in its local-name. So here are the changes...

1. Break the big xsl:copy-of into 3 parts. One before the dot (.), one for the dot (.), and one for after the dot (namely employeeid). So the before bit looks like this...

   ```
    <xsl:copy-of select="
      ../../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId  |
      ../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId      |
      ../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId     |
      ../bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period" />
   ```
2. For the middle bit (in esse the xsl:copy-of select="."), we cant use a copy-of because we want to change the name. So we substitute a literal element like so ...

   ```
    <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
   ```
3. The 3rd and last bit is like the first but just for the employeeid element.

Putting it altogether, we get for our template ...

```
<xsl:template match="*">
   <projectedBalanceTotal>
     <xsl:copy-of select="
       ../../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.principalId  |
       ../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.planCodeId      |
       ../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.leaveCodeId     |
       ../bb:projected_balance_accrual_amount_for_the_pay_period" />
     <bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
     </bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate>
     <xsl:copy-of select="../../bb:projectedBalanceTotal.employeeid" />
   </projectedBalanceTotal>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is amazing!  It works really well.  I really appreciate your learning note...especially point 5.  I am scheduled to take an xlst class in 2 weeks.  I am (obviously) very new to all of this but am looking forward to learning and hopefully helping people out myself someday.

One thing I didn't specify that you mentioned in your caveat is that all "bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate\d" should have no integer, not even "1".  They should all read "bb:projectedBalanceTotal.effectiveDate" without an ending integer.

Can you help me with that last piece?

Comment: Thanks for the update and the detailed explanation.  It worked as described.  Thanks very much!!